# ssis download from https

Tags: https, ssis, token

I am new to SSIS and I am trying to download csv file from a web site. The web site is HTTPS and I have a username and password to access it.

When I login, I see that the url contains a token, such as ?token=E78335D4-83CE-11e8-8195-02D4848F6A31.
Also each of the links to download files contain that token.

How can I download these files in SSIS?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: You should start this task by googling and trying something. It took me five seconds to find this: http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Downloading-a-file-over-HTTP-the-SSIS-way.aspx. Please try it and get back with an actual issue.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I didn't mention it, but I have been googling. I'm just not seeing anything about how to handle the token that is required with each download.

Comment: There's nothing in your question to give any clue about how the token is generated. Is the token delivered when you log in? Probably. That would make this a multistep process 1. Login and get token; 2. Send request with token. That is already too complicated for out of the box SSIS tasks and you need to go to using a C# script task.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry I didn't form my question well.In spite of that you did get it right, there is a login screen, then a listing of files available, almost like an FTP. I have managed to put together a FTP package and I was hoping this would be as simple. I was afraid it would involve C#. I'm a VBA guy trying to learn SSIS. Thanks for your patience. Do you think a third party tool like CozyRoc would allow me to achieve this without scripting?

Comment: I don't know if CozyRoc will help you here. It depends on how this web page works, which is still a mystery. It's not a huuuuge leap from VBA to C# but you will need to learn about web technologies as well. For example your first step would be to use something like PostMan to try and log in directly using a POST and capture the resulting token

Comment: Thanks Nick. I think that the web technologies is where I am weak and that is why all the solutions I find online are not clear to me.I guess I need to work through a simple tutorial on downloading from HTTP first, then work my way up to this task with HTTPS and tokens.